# How to extract trained caffe kernels filter of the first layer

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, caffe

I am using caffe and I wonder if I just can use one of the filters separately.
So basically I just need the trained kernel of that filters (using in the first layer).
I could not find the formula of the kernels in the paper.
So I really appreciate it if someone can help me out please.
If you can also tell me how to extract them in matlab version I would be so grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Also, SO is not a place where other's write your code, please list what you've found, and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: What is the paper you are referring to? Also, what have you already tried? Stack Overflow will help you with issues in your own code but will not write it completely for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a trained net with its `'deploy.prototxt'` file defining the net, and the trained parameters at `'my_weights.caffemodel'` file.
Suppose the layer you are interested in is defined like this in `'deploy.prototxt`':

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
  }
}
```

As you can see the layer's name is `"conv1"` it has 32 filters of size 5-by-5.

First, you need to load the net in Matlab

```
 >> net = get_net( 'path/to/deploy.prototxt', 'path/to/my_weights.caffemodel', 'test' );
```

Once you load the net, you can access its parameters using the layer's name

```
>> w = net.params( 'conv1', 1 ).get();
```